# ¿Como hago para validar un xml mediante un esquema xsd y si todos los tags no son validos se guarden en un nuevo xml los que si lo sean?

Tags: python-3.x

Este es el código que estoy probando y no funciona

```
xsd_doc = xmlschema.XMLSchema('protocolo/schema-definition.xsd')
xml_doc = XET.parse('protocolo/buffer.xml')
new_root = XET.Element("root")

for element in xml_doc.iter():
    if xsd_doc.is_valid(element):
        new_root.append(element)

new_xml = XET.tostring(new_root)
new_xml = new_xml.replace(b"<root>", b"").replace(b"</root>", b"")
with open('protocolo/valid.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(new_xml)
```

Funciona bien cuando el xml es totalmente valido, pero si algún elemento no lo es no se guarda nada y necesito que los que si lo sean se guarden en un nuevo xml

Answer (score 0):

la idea de la creacion de un xml si lo que quieres hacer es en un contexto de facturacion es que cuente con un esquema y no se guarde si el documento esta mal estructurado ya que esto puede significar que o el archivo fue alterado o no se genero correctamente ante el sat.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).